# Simulator device returned an error for the requested operation

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, watchos

**i am using watchOS 9.4
i rest simulator  but nothing works,
secondly the simulator does not boot with out running app while other simulator boot up that is running on watchOS 8.5

Simulator device returned an error for the requested operation.
**

```
Domain: FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain
Code: 5
Failure Reason: Unexpected error type.
User Info: {
  BSErrorCodeDescription = InvalidResponse;
  IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
  SimCallingSelector = "launchApplicationWithID:options:pid:error:";
}
--
The request to open ".watchkitapp" failed.
Domain: FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain
Code: 5
Failure Reason: Unexpected error type.
User Info: {
  BSErrorCodeDescription = InvalidResponse;
}
```